# Generic method java 6 <T> before return type

Tags: java, generics

What is the difference between:

```
public <T> void createArray(T sample){
    ArrayList<T> list = new ArrayList<T>();
    list.add(sample);
}
```

and

```
public void createArray(T sample){
    ArrayList<T> list = new ArrayList<T>();
    list.add(sample);
}
```

I read that the method signature for using types should have `<T>` before the return type but how come I am still able to create the method without the `<T>`? What is the implication if I do or do not put it?

Comment: The answer given are probably right, but note that, as is, your `createArray` in the second snippet does NOT compile.

Comment: one of the Best explanations i recommend it
http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-generics/methods.html

Answer (score 33, accepted):

In the second method, the type parameter would be typically defined in the class declaration to which the method belongs:

```
class MyClass<T> {
   public void createArray(T sample){
      ArrayList<T> list = new ArrayList<T>();
      list.add(sample);
   }
   ...
}
```

So the second method belongs to a generic type.
The first method is a *generic method* because it defines its own type parameter.

Answer (score 14):

In the first case, the generic parameter `T` is defined for the method. Other methods may have a different `T`.

In the second case, the generic parameter `T` is defined for the class or interface. All methods within that class or interface must have the same `T`.

Defining a class-wide generic allows you to enforce the same type parameter on many methods. You can also have fields of the generic type. See `ArrayList<t>` for an example.

Comment: The straight-forward simple answer I was looking for...

Answer (score 7):

From the second example, I am guessing this method is defined in a generic class something like this:

```
class SomeClass<T> {
  public void createArray(T sample){ ... }
}
```

The difference between the first and second example is that in the first example, the `T` is effectively a "local" type variable. You could give it a different name, e.g. `S`, to make it a little bit clearer:

```
class SomeClass<T> {
  public <S> void createArray(S sample){ ... }
}
```

So, `S` and `T` are both type variables, but are unrelated. `T` is defined at class scope, and so can be used to refer to the same type amongst all methods in the class; `S` is defined only at method scope.

By using the name `T` instead of `S`, you are hiding the class-level type variable, `T`. This means that, for example, the following would not work:

```
class SomeClass<T> {
  public T getWotsit() { ... }
  public <T> void createArray(T sample){
    T wotsit = getWotsit();
  }
}
```

because the `T` in the signature of `getWotsit` and the `T` in the variable declaration `T wotsit` potentially refer to different types; this is more clear if you use the name `S` to write the equivalent code:

```
class SomeClass<T> {
  public T getWotsit() { ... }
  public <S> void createArray(S sample){
    S wotsit = getWotsit();
  }
}
```

As far as I'm aware, there is no way to refer to the class-level type variable if you've defined a method-level type variable with the same name.

However, both of the following would be fine:

```
class SomeClass<T> {
  public T getWotsit() { ... }
  // No additional type variable, so T is the class-level type variable.
  public void createArray(T sample){  
    T wotsit = getWotsit();
  }
}

class SomeClass<T> {
  public T getWotsit() { ... }
  // Type variable has different name, so `T` is the class-level
  // type variable.
  public <S> void createArray(T sample){
    T wotsit = getWotsit();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In case of `public void createArray(T sample)` where `T` is defined in class definition `MyClass<T>` is generic for the class

For `public <T> void createArray(T sample){` ,  `T` is local generic for method and is not related to `T` in `MyClass<T>`, this `T` could be anything X,Y,Z. If you remove `<T>` before void,   it is now `<T>` from `MyClass<T>` and cannot be X,Y,Z